# GetComponent returning 0 in Unity Game Engine

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I´m having a unity problem with getting a variable from another script. I´m working in c#. 
In this case I´m getting the health of the player to the GUI script, but the variable just returns 0. I tried to understand by searching for similar problems but i could not figure it out. Thanks! /PixzleOne

How the health is set in the player script in the monobehavior part:

```
public int health = 100;
```

How I tried to get the health in the GUI script:

```
int playerHealth;
public GameObject player;
void Update () {
    playerHealth = player.GetComponent<playerScript>().health;
    print (playerHealth); //Only for me to see if it returns anything.
}
```

Comment: Is the variable changed in the inspector for that object? Inspector values will override script-defined values.

Comment: Yes! Thank you very much! Write it as a answer and I'll mark it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have the value changed in the inspector for the object. Inspector values will override script-defined values.

An important thing to note - if you previously declared your `public` variable (also referred to as an inspector variable) without a default value like so:

```
public int myValue;
```

then update it with a value in the script:

```
public int myValue = 1;
```

the inspector *will not* pick up the change. You'll have to change it in the inspector yourself. I remember this getting me stuck at one point when I first started with Unity.

When in doubt, check the inspector.